# How to rename multiple folders that have a set number of files within that folder using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, rename

I am very new to programming so your help is much appreciated!

I have a top directory, containing subfolders which have files in them. I want to add the string "x" after the folder name e.g. foldername -> foldernamex *if* the subfolders contain less than 4 or greater than 4 files. How do I go about doing this?

Here is my attempt so far:

```
for %%e in ('dir ^| find "File(s)"') do ( 
set cnt=%%e echo File count = %cnt% 
 if File count <4 do ren "%%e" "%%~nxf_x" 
)
```

Comment: Here is my attempt...                                                                                for %%e in ('dir ^| find "File(s)"') do (
 set cnt=%%e
 echo File count = %cnt%
 if File count <4 do ren "%%e" "%%~nxf_x"
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses the `dir` command and the brief `/b` switch with the file-only switch `/a-d` and pipes the result through the `find /c /v ""` command to count the number of files.

`findstr` is used to find the exact numeral `4` and if it doesn't detect `4` then the script renames the folder and restarts the loop to handle nested subdirectories (because the folder structure changes when a folder is renamed).

It's not tested - so test it on a sample folder tree with copies of some folders first.

```
@echo off
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad ^|findstr /v /i "x$" ') do (
  dir "%%a" /b /a-d 2>nul |find /c /v "" |findstr "^4$" >nul || (ren "%%a" "%%~nxax" & goto :loop)
)
pause
```

Simpler code for processing only the folders inside the current folder.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad ') do (
  dir "%%a" /b /a-d 2>nul |find /c /v "" |findstr "^4$" >nul || ren "%%a" "%%~nxax"
)
pause
```

Comment: it almost works. when a folder has less than 4 files, it renames with excess xxxxxxxxxxxx e.g. foldername -> foldernamexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: I added a filter so that the same folder isn't renamed twice or more - but it will not rename any folders that already have `x` at the end of the name.  You need to change x in two places. in `"x$"` and in `ax"`

Comment: what do you mean by change x in two places? The code so far renames the folder with excess x and I get a message that the file name is too long.

Comment: Yes. Though I get the desired result when I remove :loop in the 2nd line and "% goto :loop" in the 4th line

Comment: Did you remove your test folders and copy new test folders?  The `:loop` is to handle nested subdirectories.  If you don't have any then it isn't needed.

Comment: Yes everytime I ran the test script. Otherwise if I dont remove the :loop, then folders that were renamed have excess 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Comment: I've tested it here.  Only the first version did that.

Comment: Tested the first script again. It works, thanks alot!